# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in view file

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

may i know why this code showing invalid argument supplied for foreach() and how i should correct it ?

```
  @foreach($project_details as $project) {

       @foreach($project->projectusers as $users) {
          {{ $user->name }}  
       }
      @endforeach }

  @endforeach
```

Controller

```
  public function index()
      {

     $this->project = Project::with('projectusers')->get();      
      return view('projects.index',  [
       'project_details' => $this->project
     ]);

}
```

Comment: either `$project_details` or `$project->projectusers` is not an array (or iterable object) as foreach() expects.

Comment: how i can correct it?

Comment: standard php debugging - var_dump() everything until you understand what you have, what you don't have and how to make it what you need..

Comment: Can you please show your projectusers function in Project model.

Answer (score 0):

projectusers is a relationship ? Do you use the `with()` function in your Eloquent query to get that relationship within the collection ?

In addition, in your foreach code, you use the plural for users (`$project->projectusers as $users`), and then in the double brackets, you use the singular `{{ $user->name }}`
Remove the 's' from users in the foreach and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on foreach() a little more:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

But if this is your entire code, you have not set any array values or assigned any values from a database or anything

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Using the website above you can see it is quite simple to fill an array yourself depending on how many values you need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `compact` as a second argument of your `view()`

```
 public function index()
  {

 $projects = Project::with('projectusers')->get();

  return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
 }
```

Then in your `projects.index` just call :

```
  @foreach($projects as $project) {

       @foreach($project->projectusers as $users) {
          {{ $user->name }}  
       }
      @endforeach }
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 public function index() {
          $projects = Project::whereHas('user')->get();
          return view('projects.index', compact('projects''));
```

in your blade:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
  {{$project->user->name}}
@endforeach
```